# Confused about function literals

Tags: scala

Scala newbie here.

I have a Set defined and declared as follows:

```
var g = Set(1,2,3)
```

Now I want to print out each element of the Set as follows using a function literal:

```
scala> g.foreach(s => println(s))
1
2
3
```

All is good.

I can be more concise so I do this:

```
scala> g.foreach(println)
1
2
3
```

All is good.

Now when I do this:

```
scala> g.foreach(println())
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int => ?
              g.foreach(println())
```

Why do this fail? To me (a newbie), it seems like it is the equivalent of `g.foreach(println)`. Please can someone explain the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass function literal or a function directly, like in your first two examples, you *do not invoke* that function immediately. However, in your last example you *do* immediately invoke it, because `println()` is exactly a syntax for calling functions and methods. Because `println()` result type is `Unit`, you're in fact passing a value of type `Unit` into a method which expects a value of type `(String) => Unit`, and of course these are different values, so the compiler shows an error.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the equivalent, when you pass `println`, you are passing a function that yet needs to be applied on each member of the set, on the other hand, passing `println()` is passing a `Unit`, but `foreach` needs to be passed a function that takes whatever the type of the set is and does something with it.

Comment: What do you mean by: "passing println() is passing a Unit"?

Comment: The Unit the in Scala is given to code that doesn't return any specific type. Think of it as void in Java. println() is calling the println method, which according to the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Console$) returns Unit.

Answer (score 0):

The function `println ()` prints a newline to standard output and has a return type `Unit` e.g.

```
val u: Unit = println()
```

The `foreach` function requires as its argument a function to apply to each element of the collection. `println` is such a function, which displays each argument, while `Unit` is not a function.